# How can I check the API from Eclipse editor?

Tags: xcode, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I used to use the XCode to do development, which provide me to press an "option" key while I find a method, it jumps to the document directly, how can I do the similar thing on eclipse? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctr+Click on a method and then 'Open Declaration'. Or you can use the keyboard and press 'F3'

Answer (score 0):

Shift + F2, but you have to configure your java doc first in preference

More about useful shortcut can be found in this [link](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_%283.0%29.pdf) and here is the [way](http://www.cs.laurentian.ca/aaron/cosc1047/eclipse-tutorials/javadoc-tutorial.html) to configure your javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

stand on a method and press F3 key. It'll take you to the declaration.